# How do I slow down drawing lines in tkinter to animate my plot?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I am working with lines in tkinter with the view of producing a "random walk" program. I can draw lines on a canvas but I would like to add a small delay between each new line that gets drawn. The result would be seeing more of animation rather than just have a image appear.

A small example, simpler than the whole walk:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Random Walk')
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
w = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
w.pack()
i = 0
x = 0
y = 0
while i < 10:
    w.create_line(x, y+5, x+10, y+5, fill="red")
    w.create_line(x+10, y + 5, x + 10, y + 15, fill="green")
    x = x+10
    y = y+10
    i=i+1
root.mainloop()
```

This code generates the following:
[result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn2SK.jpg)

To slow down my redraw, I have tried to use the python time module and the time.sleep() function. But I can't get it to work. I want to add say a 0.5 second delay between the drawing of each line...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Random Walk")
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
w = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
w.pack()

i = 0
x = 0
y = 0

def create_line():
    global i, x, y
    if i < 10:
        w.create_line(x, y+5, x+10, y+5, fill="red")
        w.create_line(x+10, y+5, x+10, y+15, fill="green")
        x += 10
        y += 10
        i += 1
        root.after(500, create_line)

root.after(500, create_line)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `else: pass` is useless in this case. Also usually you want to pass in integers for the time when using `root.after` instead of strings.